# Extract string using Regex and Python

Tags: python, regex

I have a column in a df contains the following values:

```py
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'Sentence':['This is the results of my experiments KEY_abc_def', 'I have researched the product KEY_abc_def as requested', 'He got the idea from your message KEY_mno_pqr']})
>>> df
                                                 Sentence
0       This is the results of my experiments KEY_abc_def
1  I have researched the product KEY_abc_def as requested
2            e got the idea from your message KEY_mno_pqr
```

I would like to use regex to extract (or duplicate) the KEY into a new column without the actual "KEY_". The output should be as below:

```py
>>> df
                                                Sentence   KEY
0      This is the results of my experiments KEY_abc_def   abc_def
1  I have researched the product KEY_abc_def as requested  abc_def
2           He got the idea from your message KEY_mno_pqr  mno_pqr
```

I tried with this code but it is not working. Any suggestions would greatly be appreciated.

```
 df['KEY']= df.Sentence.str.extract("KEY_", expand=True)
```

Comment: Please don't post images of text. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only expect word chars, that is letters, digit and underscores use

```py
df['KEY']= df['Sentence'].str.extract(r"KEY_(\w+)", expand=False)
```

If the `KEY_` must a beginning of a word, you should add `\b` word boundary in front of it: `r"\bKEY_(\w+)"`.

Since `Series.str.extract` only returns the captured text if a capturing group is used in the pattern, the regex will only return the part matched with `\w+` and `\bKEY_` will be matched but discarded from the result.